# Getting the System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException when run the app through cron job

Tags: c#, cron, window, scheduler

I have written one app which read the one file from network drive and parse the data. This application work fine when I manually running it. when I running this app through `window 7 scheduler` then its giving the `System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException`.

I have hard coded the `network drive path` like `"U:\\scripts\\file.txt"`.  I have also change the file permissions to 777 but still getting the same error. code is in C#.

Exception occur in below line.

```
fileName = "U:\\scripts\\file.txt";
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);  //exception in this line
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you map a drive in Windows, it is only mapped for the current user. Scheduled tasks don't have access to mapped drives. The simplest solution is to reference the remote file using the full UNC path. For example, if `U:` is mapped to `\\server\directory\` then your full UNC path would be:

```
\\server\directory\scripts\file.txt
```

Comment: Its working with \\server\directory\  path. Thanks for quick solution.